# ERROR exporting report from MAXIMO 7.5 to BIRT 3.7.1

Tags: birt, maximo

After updating configuration file: reporttools.properties with the following information:

*Output folder used for the export operation*
**maximo.report.birt.outputfolder=c:/BIRT7504/birt/reports**

The following error messages is shown after running EXPORTREPORT command:
*C:\BIRT7504\birt\tools>exportreports*
**The system cannot find the path specified.**

Any advice in order to fix this error message  displayed???

Comment: I don't know Maximo, but probably exportreports is a .CMD or .BAT script file. First of all, check that this script file is on your path, and find out where it is located. Then, open the file with Notepad. It will contain a line like "@echo off" near the top. Comment this out be replacing it with "rem echo off", and save the script. Now test again.This time the script will show what it's trying to do. This will help you finding out WHICH path it cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
c:\BIRT7504\birt\reports instead of c:/BIRT7504/birt/reports
```