# error editing report in birth report designer for Maximo

Tags: eclipse, birt, maximo

After using the [install guide](https://maximotimes.com/maximo/birt-maximo/birt-designer-3-7-1-development-guide/) provided by Chon I wasn't able to edit any report. The error I'm getting is

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The library with the namespace
>   "MaximoSystemLibrary" is not
>   found.    poprint.rptdesign   /MaximoReport/PO    line 2  Report Problem

I already tried solutions explained by Cherin in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313825/error-exporting-report-from-maximo-7-5-to-birt-3-7-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify that the MaximoSystemLibrary is located in the Libraries folder of your Workspace.
/Workspace/libraries/MaximoSystemLibrary.rptlibrary